# NullPointerException in MapView.getZoomLevel()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mapview

I'm getting very weird NullPointerException when trying to get current zoom level from my MapView. The problem is that this occurs not every time and happens somewhere inside **`getZoomLevel()`** function. Investigating the source code of this function shows that this is just a getter function and NullPointerException should not potentially happen here. The mapView itself is not null at the time it happens and calls to other MapView interfaces (such as `getProjection()` work fine).

Here is a brief background of my code structure:

I have map view and ItemizedOverlay with certain amount of items. When I have new data - I need to coalesce items which are close to each other. One of the params to `coalesce()` function is current zoom level which in theory I should be able to get from my MapView.

I tried to place call to `coalesce()` inside uiThread but I still get NullPointerException sometimes.

I managed to workaround this issue by keeping track of last known zoomLevel within my custom map view and returning it when `getZoomLevel` fails:

```
public final int getCurrentZoomLevel() 
{
    try 
    {
        return this.getZoomLevel();
    } catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return lastZoomLevel;
    }
}
```

But still, I'm curious why it happens.
It happens on different devices and different Android versions.

Here is stack trace:

```
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.getZoomLevel(MapView.java:1094)
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at com.inrix.lib.view.CustomMapView.getCurrentZoomLevel(CustomMapView.java:195)
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at com.inrix.lib.mapitems.incidents.IncidentMapItemOverlay.performCoalesceInternal(IncidentMapItemOverlay.java:109)
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at com.inrix.lib.mapitems.MapItemsOverlay$4.run(MapItemsOverlay.java:448)
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-18 11:31:22.435: W/System.err(8054):     at com.inrix.lib.mapitems.MapItemsOverlay.recoalesce(MapItemsOverlay.java:450)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at com.inrix.lib.mapitems.MapItemsOverlay$2.run(MapItemsOverlay.java:281)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-18 11:31:22.442: W/System.err(8054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Call to `coalesce` looks like:

```
protected void performCoalesceInternal(IOnCoalesceCompleteListener callback) 
{
    if (callback != null) 
    {
        callback.onCoalesceComplete(coalescer.coalesce(
                mapItemsController.getRawItemsCollection(), 
                MapItemType.Incident,  
                mapView.getCurrentZoomLevel(), 
                mapView.getProjection()));
    }
}
```

Please note that I have NullPointerException only on `getZoomLevel()` call. `mapView.getProjection()` works fine.

Activity creation/initialization stage:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ........

    this.setContentView(R.layout.content_inrixmap_activity);

    // Initialize map.
    this.mapView = (CustomMapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    ........

    // Create overlays.
    this.currentLocationOverlay = new CurrentLocationOverlay(this.mapView);
    this.trafficTileOverlay = new TrafficTileOverlay(new TrafficTileManager(this, this.trafficTileHandler));
    this.cameraOverlay = new CameraMapItemOverlay(this, this.mapView, this);
    this.incidentsOverlay = new IncidentMapItemOverlay(this, this.mapView, this);

    // Add overlays to map.
    this.mapView.addOverlay(this.trafficTileOverlay);
    this.mapView.addOverlay(this.currentLocationOverlay);
    this.mapView.addOverlay(this.cameraOverlay);
    this.mapView.addOverlay(this.incidentsOverlay);
    this.mapView.preLoad();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for when you create your map activity?

Comment: @BlaineOmega not sure what are you interested in, since activity code is massive and there is no reason to paste all that code in here. However I have updated my question with activity creation/initialization code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is a bit specific to my code. Apparently, android caches instance of a mapView to be processed by a callback. And when my activity gets recreated, callback uses old instance which is valid, but unitialized.

Solved by cancelling all active network requests when mapView gets recreated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you called populate after adding new data to the Itemized Overlay?

Good luck,
Luis

Comment: Yes, I am sure I call populate after I add items to overlay. I just didn't get how `populate()` and ItemizedOverlay related to NullPointerException in mapView. Overlay should not affect zoom level in any way. Isn't it?